# Sql join and group by statement is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables product and stock. In product table there is a column which signifies the minimum quantity. From the stock table I need to identify the products for which stock quantity is less than minimum quantity. I have tried with the below query but it is not working.

```
select
    s.product_name,
    s.mfg_company,
    s.category,
    sum(s.quantity) as quantity,
    p.min_quantity
from stock as s
join product as p on p.product_name = s.product_name 
where p.min_quantity!=''
group by s.product_name
having p.min_quantity > sum(s.quantity)
```

In the attached screenshot please notice the output is not correct.
[image]

sample data of stock and product table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP7ct.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGmnH.png)

Comment: Add all information as text not as image. Add sample data and expected result

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _it is not working_ Do you mean that it is not giving you your expected result? You also wrote: _notice the output is not correct_ Pardon me, but how is it incorrect and what should it be?

Comment: in the output you can see the min quantity is less than the stock quantity for the 2 entries so as per the condition written in sql these entries should not populate.

Comment: Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. both sample table data _and_ the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links to images.)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't grouping by all non-aggregated columns, which for MySQL only returns the first row found for each group by if the server settings allow it.

Group by all non-aggregated columns by replacing

```
group by s.product_name
```

with

```
group by 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: Seems like OP is suddenly using SQLite, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data - stocks:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stocks (STOCK_ID INTEGER, PRODUCT_NAME TEXT, MFG_COMPANY TEXT, CATEGORY TEXT, QUANTITY INTEGER);
INSERT INTO stocks (STOCK_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, MFG_COMPANY, CATEGORY, QUANTITY) 
VALUES
  (55, 'FAN-SURYA', 'SURYA', 'FAN', 0),
  (56, 'CFL-SURYA', 'SURYA', 'CFL', 5),
  (57, 'CFL-ANCHOR', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', 1),
  (58, 'CFL-HEVELS', 'HEVELS', 'CFL', 2),
  (59, 'CFL-ANCHOR', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', 4),
  (60, 'CFL-VGUARD', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', 6),
  (61, 'CFL-TT', 'CA', 'DS', 10),
  (62, 'DFSDF', 'DSFSDF', 'DSFSDF', 7),
  (65, 'CFL-ANCHOR', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', 2),
  (66, 'FAN-SURYA', 'SURYA', 'FAN', 10),
  (67, 'CFL-SURYA1', 'SURYA', 'CFL', 5),
  (68, 'CFL-SURYA1', 'SURYA', 'CFL', 3);
```

Sample Data - products:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (PRODUCT_ID INTEGER, PRODUCT_NAME TEXT, MFG_COMPANY TEXT, CATEGORY TEXT, MIN_QUANTITY INTEGER);
INSERT INTO products (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, MFG_COMPANY, CATEGORY, MIN_QUANTITY)
VALUES
  (22330, 'CFL-ANCHOR', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', 6),
  (22331, 'CFL-HEVELS', 'HEVELS', 'CFL', null),
  (22332, 'FAN-HEVELS', 'HEVELS', 'FAN', null),
  (22333, 'FAN-SURYA', 'SURYA', 'FAN', 5),
  (22334, 'CFL-SURYA', 'SURYA', 'CFL', null),
  (22335, 'CFL-VGUARD', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', null),
  (22336, 'CFL-TT', 'CA', 'DS', 2),
  (22337, 'DFSDF', 'DSFSDF', 'DSFSDF', 2),
  (22338, 'CFL-ANCHOR1', 'ANCHOR', 'CFL', null),
  (22339, 'GHFGH', 'SSSSS', 'SSSS', 9),
  (22340, 'CFL-SURIA1', 'SURIA', 'CFL', 2);
```

**Your query** from the question:

```sql
select
    s.product_name,
    s.mfg_company,
    s.category,
    sum(s.quantity) as quantity,
    p.min_quantity
from stocks as s
join products as p on p.product_name = s.product_name 
where p.min_quantity!=''
group by s.product_name
having p.min_quantity > sum(s.quantity)
```

**... Returns no rows**
But if you remove the HAVING clause then you will get the result showing you that there are no rows having minimal quantity grater than stock quantity...

```sql
/*    Result of your SQL without HAVING clause    */
PRODUCT_NAME    MFG_COMPANY  CATEGORY   quantity     MIN_QUANTITY
--------------  -----------  ---------  ----------   ------------
CFL-ANCHOR      ANCHOR       CFL                7               6
CFL-TT          CA           DS                10               2
DFSDF           DSFSDF       DSFSDF             7               2
FAN-SURYA       SURYA        FAN               10               5       */
```

However, you should do the grouping by all columns from the selection list that are not aggregated. You should consider to treat null values as they are not values at all - using Is Null / Is Not Null or using dedicated functions to control your results ( Coalesce() ). Here it doesn't change anything but in some other cases it could change the results significantly.
The same result as your code (without having clause) could be like this:

```sql
Select      s.PRODUCT_NAME,
            s.MFG_COMPANY,
            s.CATEGORY,
            Sum(s.QUANTITY) as STOCK_QUANTITY,
            Coalesce(p.MIN_QUANTITY, 0) as MIN_QUANTITY
From        stocks s
Inner Join  products p ON (p.PRODUCT_NAME = s.PRODUCT_NAME)
Where       p.MIN_QUANTITY Is Not Null
Group By    s.PRODUCT_NAME, s.MFG_COMPANY, s.CATEGORY, Coalesce(p.MIN_QUANTITY, 0)
/*Having      Coalesce(p.MIN_QUANTITY, 0) > Sum(s.QUANTITY)*/
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
PRODUCT_NAME    MFG_COMPANY  CATEGORY   STOCK_QUANTITY   MIN_QUANTITY
--------------  -----------  ---------  --------------   ------------
CFL-ANCHOR      ANCHOR       CFL                     7              6
CFL-TT          CA           DS                     10              2
DFSDF           DSFSDF       DSFSDF                  7              2
FAN-SURYA       SURYA        FAN                    10              5       */
```

... see it here --> https://dbfiddle.uk/2Htx-47S